# groupByKey creates repartition topic even though there is no key change

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement a simple event sourced service with the help of kafka streams (Kafka 1.0.1) with and spring cloud stream (2.0.0-build-snapshot). My StreamListener method just reads a Kstream of events corresponding to state changes of my aggregate and applies them on the aggregate and saves the latest state in the local state store (kafka provided state store). The domain event messages also have the same key as the aggregate's uuid(String). Here is the code:

```java
@StreamListener(Channels.EVENTS_INPUT_CHANNEL)
public void listen(KStream<String, DomainEvent> stream) {
    Serde<DomainEvent> domainEventSerde = new JsonSerde<>(DomainEvent.class);
    Serde<Slot> slotSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Slot.class);
    stream
        .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), domainEventSerde))
        .aggregate(
                Slot::new, 
                (s, domainEvent, slot) -> slot.handle(domainEvent),
                Materialized.<String, Slot, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                as(Repository.SNAPSHOTS_FOR_SLOTS)
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(slotSerde)
        );
}
```

The above code produces a changelog topic (as expected): **slot-service-slots-changelog**. Although it also creates a repartition topic: **slot-service-slots-repartition**. Both topics seem to have exactly the same messages (keys and values). My understanding was that if there are no key-modifying operations done on the stream, re-partitioning is not required. Am I missing something here?

**Update:**
This might not be required anymore as sobychacko has provided the explanation, however I did try without cloud stream binding like below and it did not create the re-partition topic:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, DomainEvent> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    ProducerFactory<String,DomainEvent> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> config() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return config;
    }

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    StreamsConfig streamsConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "slot-service");
        return new StreamsConfig(config);
    }

    @Bean
    KTable<String, Slot> kTable(KStreamBuilder builder) {
        Serde<DomainEvent> domainEventSerde = new JsonSerde<>(DomainEvent.class);
        Serde<Slot> slotSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Slot.class);

        return
                builder
                .stream(Serdes.String(), domainEventSerde, Repository.SLOT_EVENTS)
                .groupByKey(Serdes.String(), domainEventSerde)
                .aggregate(
                    Slot::new, 
                    (s, domainEvent, slot) -> slot.handle(domainEvent),
                    slotSerde,
                    Repository.SNAPSHOTS_FOR_SLOTS);
    }

    }
```

Also, the producer is as follows:

```
@Autowired
    public Repository(KafkaTemplate<String, DomainEvent> kafkaTemplate, KStreamBuilderFactoryBean kStreamBuilderFactoryBean) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        this.kStreamBuilderFactoryBean = kStreamBuilderFactoryBean;
    }

    public void save(Slot slot) {
        List<DomainEvent> newEvents = slot.getDirtyEvents();
        newEvents.forEach(
            domainEvent -> kafkaTemplate.send(SLOT_EVENTS, domainEvent.aggregateUUID().toString(),domainEvent) 
        );
        slot.flushEvents();
    }
```

**Update 2:**

Here is the producer code with cloud stream:

```
public void save(Slot slot) {
        List<DomainEvent> newEvents = slot.getDirtyEvents();
        newEvents.forEach(domainEvent -> channels.eventsOutputChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(domainEvent)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, slot.getUuid().toString()).build()));
        slot.flushEvents();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this has to do anything with the spring cloud stream binder. Could you try the code with Kafka Streams directly and see how that goes? I think you will see the same behavior there.

Comment: The question is, where does the input stream come from? It's just passed in as a parameter -- maybe, the input stream was created with a key-changing operation? Note, that repartitioning topics are inserted "lazily" -- ie, if you do `map()` operation, this only set's a flag and does not repartition immediately -- a consecutive `groupByKey()` checks this flag and might create a repartition topic if required.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax. There is a map() operation that happens before the method where we do inbound deserialization (I assume the native deserialization is disabled in the example above). I think you can enable nativeDecoding and use a Serde provided by Kafka to avoid that map() operation. The JsonSerde used in the code above cannot be currently used as a property as it needs the class information, but in the next version of spring-cloud-stream binder, we will make it easier to use that as a property so that you can use that as a Serde.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarification @sobychacko -- you should put this as an answer (you can include my comment in your answer, too).

Comment: Thanks sobychacko and Matthias J. Sax. I have updated the post with non-cloud stream consumer and producer code as well as cloud-stream producer code for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a map() operation that happens before the method is invoked where we do inbound deserialization (I assume the native deserialization is disabled in the example above). As Matthias pointed out, if there is a `map()` operation, that sets a flag and in a subsequent `groupByKey()` a repartition topic is created. So, this is whats probably happening in your situation as the framework does this `map` operation for you as part of the inbound message conversion. If you really want to avoid creating this repartition topic, you can enable `nativeDecoding` and then use a `Serde` provided by Kafka. This way the `map` operation is not invoked by the framework. The problem is that the `JsonSerde` used in your code is not easily used as a Serde property in Spring Cloud Stream as it requires the class information. In the next version of Spring Cloud Stream, we are going to improve this situation. In the meantime, you can provide a custom Serde. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @sobychacko. That explains the behaviour

Comment: Also, is there a github issue that I can track?